# Does merging libreoffice and openoffice make sense?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Does it make sense to merge [openoffice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openoffice) and [libreoffice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice) (I'm talking about the tags on this site, of course)? They're technically different software, but very similar, and unlikely to diverge much.

Comment: Would applying my logic behind my answer to the [tag:rhel], [tag:centos] part of [my previous answer](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605/does-the-split-in-red-hat-and-suse-tags-make-sense) make any sense?  Looking at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice#Comparison_with_OpenOffice.org) there are already a few differences, and as it's a fork I'd expert more to turn up. Of course, it could be merged until a time that the differences are that many that it's needed.

Comment: @NJ I think the situation is different. LibreOffice and OpenOffice haven't diverged much (yet), and LibreOffice is often branded as OpenOffice which will lead to confusion.

Comment: then I think the latter option, merge them until a time that the differences are that many that it's needed.

Comment: “unlikely to diverge much” – I disagree. From the time of the fork they have had a different philosophy altogether, so divergence was inevitable. LibreOffice took the community with them and started rewriting all of the crap code, whereas OpenOffice was left to try to make something commercial out of it and started stripping out all of the copyleft LGPL code. There is a reason why everyone has been switching to LibreOffice you know. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah; I can't imagine actually needing distinct tags. I kept [openoffice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openoffice); there's a synonym for [libreoffice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice) now

Answer (score 12):

These packages have actually already started to diverge and are likely to do so more. In particular the LibreOffice suite is integrating patches and making radical changes to different platforms including a a revamped rendering engine and changing the background technology on some platforms. Some plugins are already poking up as incompatible with one or the other suite.

Be prepared to un-alias this when issues start showing up with "works for me" answers and it turns out they aren't comparing apples and apples.