# Unalias libreoffice from the openoffice tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I suggest unaliasing the [libreoffice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice) tag from [openoffice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openoffice). The two codebases are diverging more and more and LibreOffice is getting more attention in most cases. Also see https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/614/22886

Comment: I would very much like to second this, particularly of questions seeking help they are now significantly different and solutions may apply to only one.

Comment: Second! Actually, third =)

Comment: You might be interested in this http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230967/213575

Answer (score 2):

They're separated now. Somebody will still need to go through [openoffice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openoffice) and find any posts that are specific to [libreoffice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice)